# How to execute a custom validator client function OnBlur or OnChange

Tags: .net, asp.net, validation, client-side, customvalidator

I have a standard ASP.NET (WebForms, not MVC) custom validator assigned to a TextBox. I want the TextBox event OnBlur (or OnChange) to trigger the client-side validation function specified by the Customer Control. Way back in .Net 1.1 I could call "ValidatorHookupControl" to wire this up "OnLoad" but that is apparently no longer part of the infrastructure, so how does one accomplish this?

I am guessing its something obvious, but so far it escape me, and too many hours have passed going in circles... any help appreciated.

Note: I want to stay within the .Net Validation structure so that "onBlur" validation errors are reported in the same place / format (aka Validation Summary) as the other Validators that are fired at submit time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a custom validator, even [`CustomValidator.ClientValidationFunction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx).

If you want to use ASP.NET validation infrastructure, inherit from BaseValidator and subscribe using JavaScript (I recommend to use jQuery) to target control's event you need. And the perform the validation.

---

Or you can use `CustomValidator.ClientValidationFunction`. Inherit from CustomValidator, on (probably) `Control.PreInit()` subscribe validator's function to target control's event you need, and wait the function to be called.

Comment: I'm fuzzy here.. not sure why I would create a custom control but assuming I did (say MyControl), how would you wire the target Control's Client-side event to MyControl's Client Side Validation funtiohn?

Comment: Oh my... so simple - 'ValidatorOnHookup' is no longer required because its done automatically... 

I didn't realize that because my ClientValidationFunction wasn't firing. 

That **appears** to be because the CustomValidator tag included a Visible="false" attribute.

As soon as removed that, the client function executed.

Problem Solved.